# php difference between function exit and return false

Tags: php

I have seen at the end of the function sometimes written "return false" also "exit". What is the main difference between these two and in which kind of situations are these two required?

Comment: `exit` terminates the script (optionally displaying a message), `return` returns a value from a function.... pretty fundamentally different. Read docs (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) for more details

Comment: You can get returned status by using it inside of a file `$var = include './test.php';` and in test.php file `return false;`

Answer (score 3):

exit will ends PHP execution, while return will ends the function, use return for most cases, it depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

`return false` is for functions and `exit` is for stopping the php script

Answer (score 2):

"return" is exiting of function, "exit" is terminating of whole script.

[exit description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

[return description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Answer (score 1):

exit() halts the entire PHP program and return to the OS.

return, on the other hand, ends a function call and returns to the caller.

Comment: *OS* ? Uhm we are talking about PHP ...

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV - incredible, but it's true.... you can run php scripts from the command line, not just from a web browser

Comment: @MarkBaker It makes sense now !