# how to stop a PHP function

Tags: php

i have this following code, and i need to stop the fucntion if the first IF is true, i wan't execute the rest of the code.

Could you help me ?
Thank you ! :)

```
function valideInfosReclamation($date,$idSite,$idNature,$idActivite){
    if($date==""){
        ajouterErreur("Le champ date ne doit pas être vide");
    }
    else{
        if(!estDatevalide($date)){
          ajouterErreur("Date invalide");
        } 
    }
    if($idSite || $idNature || $idActivite == ""){
        ajouterErreur("Certains champs sont vides et doivent êtres remplis");
    }
}
```

Comment: [return](http://php.net/return).

Comment: possible duplicate of [php difference between function exit and return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633028/php-difference-between-function-exit-and-return-false)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Stopping the execution of the calling function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368937/php-stopping-the-execution-of-the-calling-function)

Answer (score 8):

Use `return`, it will exit the function. Here, I stop the function after each `ajouterErreur()` call.

```
function valideInfosReclamation($date,$idSite,$idNature,$idActivite){
    if($date==""){
        ajouterErreur("Le champ date ne doit pas être vide");
        return ;
    } else {
        if(!estDatevalide($date)){
          ajouterErreur("Date invalide");
          return ;
        } 
    }
    if($idSite || $idNature || $idActivite == ""){
        ajouterErreur("Certains champs sont vides et doivent êtres remplis");
        return ;
    }
}
```

It's just an example, try to limit the use of `return` instructions in your function, as it is not a good practise to have more than one or two...

Comment: Using multiple returns is an easy way out, but I do not think that it is best practise. It can make the program flow very hard to read.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag True, here it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

you can stop with `die();` all of program.